# resultado de observable se actualiza antes de la operacion angular firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, observable

Tengan saludos, estoy realizando unas actualizaciones en firestore con angular de una tabla que se tiene que actualizar en otras dos tablas, para ello requiero ubicar todas las ubicaciones a actualizar y tengo el siguiente codigo:

Un service con la siguiente función:

```
  public getProductos(id: string) {
    return this.afs.collection('COLECCION', ref => ref.where('KEYS', 'array-contains', id)).snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions =>
        actions.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data() as ProductoI;
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;
          return { id, ...data };
        })
      )
    );
  }
```

en el component lo siguiente:

```
var form = {id:'xxx'}

this.productosSvc.getProductos(form.id).subscribe(r => {
      console.log('PRODUCTOS', r);
      r.forEach(s => {
        let tempP = s;
        delete tempP.id; //Aca borro la propiedad id porque no la necesito para tempP
        let idx = tempP.tiposppkeys.indexOf(form.id);
        while (idx != -1) {
          console.log('idx', idx)
          tempP.tipospp[idx] = form;
          idx = tempP.tiposppkeys.indexOf(form.id, idx + 1);
        }
        console.log('PROD ORIGINAL', s); //Aca debe contener el id
        console.log('PROD COPIA', tempP); //Aca no necesito el id
        this.comprasSvc.getCompras(s.id).subscribe(t => { //Aca requiero la propiedad id para hacer otra busqueda
          console.log('COMPRAS',t) //no me funciona porque no encuentra el id en s
        })
      })
    })
```

Mi problema es que cuando borro la propiedad id del objeto tempP, también se borra en el resultado en s, no entiendo a que se debe, disculpen soy nuevo en esto, espero puedan ayudarme y mas que todo entender como funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En javascript todos los tipos de datos que no sean primitivos(`boolean, number, null, undefined, string y Symbol`) es decir, `objects` se guardan por referencia. Es decir, dicho dato solo existe una vez en memoria, pero las variables que hacen referencia a dicho objeto comparten referencia(puntero) al mismo objeto.

En tu caso, si `s` es un objeto estas guardando una referencia(puntero) en `let tempP = s;` no guardas el valor en `tempP;` sino la dirección de memoria en la que se encuentra. Por lo tanto, cuando modificas/borras el objeto estas modificando la instancia que hay en memoria no lo que contiene `tempP`.

Si quieres hacer un clone de un objeto puedes usar `Object.assign` o el `... (spread operator)`.

Si `s` es un objeto que contiene otros objetos dentro esta manera no te sirve ya que `Object.assign` y `spread operator` hacen un `shallow copy` de los datos. Es decir, crean una variable nueva en memoria pero comparten la referencia al objeto que ya existe en memoria. Puedes mirar de usar alguna manera de hacer `deep copy` para crear datos nuevos sin referencias.

Puedes probar esto

```
let tempP = {...s}; // copia todas las propiedades de s en tempP
```

Espero haberme explicado, es un poco difícil expresar ciertos conceptos.

Comment: en efecto funcionó. Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: si te sirvió acepta la respuesta porfavor.